# Can't uncheck constrain to margin

Tags: xcode, uitableview, autolayout

When I was trying to put an ImageView inside a custom cell ,I wanna the image take up all spaces in that cell without margin. But I found there is always a grey margin on the left of the cell.

I thought it was a problem of Constrain to Margin but the checkbox seems to be grey, and it will keep checked even if I uncheck it.It will just back to checked status...  I can't uncheck it, and I also uncheck those Relative to Margin on my constraints, that didn't work either... I'm so confused.

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: are you adding your constraints with interface builder?

Comment: same problem here....have u got the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the constant value of your margins to `-16`

Comment: In the storyboard view, it seems to be correct but the margin still shows up when running the program.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can't ... Reputation not enough